# Why do compiled .ko files differ in Yocto work directory

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to understand Loadable Kernel Modules for Yocto.
So I followed a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5G_rT-GwPE) and the [docs](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/kernel-dev/common.html#incorporating-out-of-tree-modules) to add the `hello-mod` recipe to my image.

The command `bitbake hello` finishes successfully.
Now I want to inspect the output: `find . -iname "*hello*.ko"` shows there are eight different versions of `hello.ko` in my build directory.

- Why do they differ, while coming from the same source?
- (Which one can I put on the board for debugging purposes?)*

The files are (I prefixed identical files with A,B,C,D):

```
A ./tmp/work/myimg/hello/0.1-r0/packages-split/hello-dbg/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/.debug/hello.ko
B ./tmp/work/myimg/hello/0.1-r0/packages-split/kernel-module-hello-4.14.98/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/hello.ko
A ./tmp/work/myimg/hello/0.1-r0/package/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/.debug/hello.ko
B ./tmp/work/myimg/hello/0.1-r0/package/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/hello.ko
C ./tmp/work/myimg/hello/0.1-r0/sysroot-destdir/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/hello.ko
D ./tmp/work/myimg/hello/0.1-r0/hello.ko
D ./tmp/work/myimg/hello/0.1-r0/image/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/hello.ko
C ./tmp/sysroots-components/myimg/hello/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/hello.ko
```

Comparing them with diff, shows pairs of them are identical.

```
Files ./tmp.../packages-split/hello-dbg/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/.debug/hello.ko and ./tmp.../package/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/.debug/hello.ko are identical
Files ./tmp.../packages-split/kernel-module-hello-4.14.98/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/hello.ko and ./tmp.../package/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/hello.ko are identical
Files ./tmp.../hello.ko and ./tmp.../image/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/hello.ko are identical
Files ./tmp/sysroots-components/depimx8mmevk/hello/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/hello.ko and ./tmp.../sysroot-destdir/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/hello.ko are identical
```

I manually copied the `ko` files over to my board. They do not work the same way as a version of the code cross-compiled for `myimg` (which is imx8m-poky-linux).

Reading the [docs](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/structure.html#build-tmp-work-tunearch-recipename-version) on the different directories printed above confuses me even more. If I understand correctly, it explicitly mentions that some files that differ in my case are copies of each other, e.g. for [populate sysroot](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/tasks.html#do-populate-sysroot): *Stages (copies) a subset of the files installed by the do_install task into the appropriate sysroot.*

**Edit:**

* Using `IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " hello"`, then the file `B` (`./tmp/work/myimg/hello/0.1-r0/package/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/hello.ko`) will be present on the target's filesystem.

Using `file`, `ls`, `strings` shows:

```
chars  size  build  name
668   40464  debug  A ./packages-split/hello-dbg/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/.debug/hello.ko
41     4200         B ./packages-split/kernel-module-hello-4.14.98/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/hello.ko
668   40464  debug  A ./package/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/.debug/hello.ko
41     4200         B ./package/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/hello.ko
39     4104         C ./sysroot-destdir/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/hello.ko
679   41744  debug  D ./hello.ko
679   41744  debug  D ./image/lib/modules/4.14.98/extra/hello.ko
```

So it boils down to the difference between `B` and `C` (probably the same as between `A` and `D`).